# How to sort a counter with Arabic in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since Arabic starts at the right side, there will be bugs if I do the following:

```
cnt = {}
cnt["پ"] = 5 # right start char
cnt["t"] = 4 # left start char
import operator
sorted(cnt, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Is there any way I could solve this problem?

Comment: @YannicHamann it does not. If you mix such kinds of chars together, the display will be weird, as mentioned in the question. I am also surprised and have no idea how to deal with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting out of `sorted` has nothing to do with the Arabic. The error you're getting out of `sorted` is because you tried to sort `cnt`, but your `key` function is written as if it's sorting `cnt.items()`. If you add the `items()` call, `sorted(cnt.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)` will behave the same regardless of whether the keys of `cnt` use Arabic characters.

As for the display issues, those *are* due to Arabic. Getting mixed RTL and LTR text to display properly isn't easy, especially in a context like source code where you can't insert formatting characters without changing the meaning. I recommend not trying to use RTL characters in source code; you could move the Arabic to an external file. I would expect most Arabic in real programs to come from external input and localization files.